# how to add existing mercurial repo to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial

I have installed mercurial plugin for Eclipse
http://www.javaforge.com/project/HGE
Question is how can i add my existing hg repository to IDE ?
I mean , i already clone my bitbucket source code to disk (without eclipse by command line), so how to add it to Eclipse now?

Answer (score 6):

1. Import it like a non version-controlled project, this varies from language to language, but begins with "File"->"Import...".
2. Once the project is imported, right-click on it in Eclipse, go to submenu "Team"->"Share Project...".
3. Select "Mercurial" then "Next >" and "Finish"
4. Done